# jsp include doesn't work for jspf files under tomcat 8 but works under the jetty

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jetty, jsp-fragments

I have the following jsp:

```
...
<jsp:include page="../imageMenu.jspf"/>
...
```

When I open following jsp when application run under the tomcat 8 I see that my include replaces with empty string.

When I run application under the jetty - it renders good.

As I  undestand the problem related with format of included file because I don't see problem with jsp files included when I run application under the tomcat.

Comment: Strange, as Jetty uses the Tomcat Jasper JSP engine also.

Answer (score 1):

Working after adding

```
<url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
```

to web.xml

result:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It's not a solution, if your servlet use a main jsp file which include a jsp fragment this solution failed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using full path.

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/JSPs/repo1/repo2/imageMenu.jspf"></jsp:include>
```