# Why doesnt a file with '.jspf' extension get processed as a 'jsp' file when included with PageContext.include()

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a web application that uses Spring MVC and jsp pages.  In one of my jsp files I have a loop that iterates over a `Map<String, Object>` and renders each entries value using `escapeXml(toString)`:

```
<c:forEach var="attr" items="${attributes}">
  <ns:entry name='${attr.key}' value='${fn:escapeXml(attr.value)}' />
</c:forEach>
```

This is obviously not a very good solution as it steals the `toString` for its purposes, and couples the markup to the model.  I want to avoid this by checking a specific folder to see if there exists a `.jspf` file with the same name as the entries key, and if so, use that fragment to render it with the `toString` approach as a fallback:

```
<c:if test="! ${fn:includeJspf(pageContext, '/WEB-INF/attributes/', ${attr.key}>
  <c:forEach var="attr" items="${attributes}">
    <ns:entry name='${attr.key}' value='${fn:escapeXml(attr.value)}' />
  </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

And my `includeJspf` function is defined:

```
public static boolean includeJspf( PageContext pageContext, String folderPath, String jspfName ) {
    String relativePath = folderPath + "/" + jspfName + ".jspf";
    if ( new File( pageContext.getServletContext().getRealPath( relativePath ) ).exists() ) {
        try {
            pageContext.getRequest().setAttribute( "parentPageContext", pageContext );
            pageContext.include( relativePath );
        }
        catch ( ServletException | IOException e ) {
            logger.warn( "Unable to include fragment [{}]: {}", relativePath, e.getMessage() );
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And my `jspf`

```
<%@ page session="false" contentType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:set var="name"
  value="${requestScope['parentPageContext'].getAttribute('attr').key}" />
<c:set var="value"
  value="${requestScope['parentPageContext'].getAttribute('attr').value}" />

<myobj:${fn:escapeXml(name)} value=${fn:escapeXml(value.value)} />
```

This fails thusly:

```
:30: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
                    <%@ page session="false" contentType="application/xml; chars
...
```

But...  If I change the extension to `jsp`, everything works perfectly.  I assume I am missing something simple like configuration in `web.xml`, but have been unable to find any documentation to explain this.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tomcat (I'm not sure about other servlet containers) you do need to add a `.jspf` mapping to the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>{jspservlet-name}</servlet-name>
    ...
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(SO source: [jsp include doesn't work for jspf files under tomcat 8 but works under the jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964247/jsp-include-doesnt-work-for-jspf-files-under-tomcat-8-but-works-under-the-jetty) - jsp:include and a programmatic include function the same I think)

However, there is some discussion about the desirability of using fragments for runtime/dynamic inclusions: [here on coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/553249/Tomcat/Scriptlets-expressions-executing-JSP-page) and [here on oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/742347).

This is a [recommendation](http://sqltech.cl/doc/oas10gR31/web.1013/b28961/workjsp.htm#i1008052%20recommendation) about it, but not the spec:

> Use the .jsp extension for top-level pages, dynamically included pages, and pages that are forwarded to—pages that are translatable on their own.

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the resources.  It makes sense.  Being dynamically included they are not part of the _including_ page as it is compiled.  So, in keeping with the _reasonable_ recommendations from your links, I think I will continue to use the `jsp` extension  due to their dynamic nature...